# Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) with [moment-jalaali.js](https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali) plugin.

moment-jalaali is a plugin for moment js that adds support for jalaali (solar) calendar.

Obviously in a web page one should first include moment.js then moment-jalaali.js in order to make it work.

I'm doing it and it's giving me the `Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined`. Google chrome says it's caused at line 31 at moment-jalaali.js :

```
require.modules = {
    moment: { exports: moment } // here the error happens
};
```

I'm using these js libraries in nopcommerce (ASP.NET application) and I'm including them like the following in admin area layout:

```
Html.AppendScriptParts(string.Format("~/Scripts/kendo/{0}/kendo.web.min.js", kendoVersion));
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/admin.common.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/moment.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/moment-jalaali.js");
```

Even if I include them before everything else, it still does not work.

Surprisingly if i make a simple html page like the following they work perfectly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="moment.js"></script>
    <script src="moment-jalaali.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What is causing the error and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

If I include `moment-jalaali.js` in the **View** itself but still include `moment.js` in the **Layout** it works fine. However it's not a proper solution so I'm still looking for a better way.

Comment: You should get `$ is not defined` error, as jQuery is loaded at the end and it's plugins are used before jQuery

Comment: @Tushar momentjs does not require jquery.

Comment: I'm solving your _future_ problems

Comment: @Tushar edited my post.

Comment: I'm seeing a Circular reference here `moment: { exports: moment }`